# How to do asynchronuous programming in Delphi?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, asynchronous, delphi-xe

I have an application, where most of the actions take some time and I want to keep the GUI responsive at all times. The basic pattern of any action triggered by the user is as follows:

1. prepare the action (in the main thread)
2. execute the action (in a background thread while keeping the gui responsive)
3. display the results (in the main thread)

I tried several things to accomplish this but all of them are causing problems in the long run (seemingly random access violations in certain situations).

1. Prepare the action, then invoke a background thread and at the end of the background thread, use `Synchronize` to call an `OnFinish` event in the main thread.
2. Prepare the action, then invoke a background thread and at the end of the background thread, use `PostMessage` to inform the GUI thread that the results are ready.
3. Prepare the action, then invoke a background thread, then busy-wait (while calling `Application.ProcessMessages`) until the background thread is finished, then proceed with displaying the results.

I cannot come up with another alternative and none of this worked perfectly for me. What is the preferred way to do this?

Comment: I have used option 2 many times without any problems. Have you tried using something like MadExcept to find out where your accvios are occurring?

Comment: Options 1 and 2 are basically the same thing and they work well. Option 3 is satanic. Don't do it.

Comment: `PostMessage` from a background thread is the correct way to inform the  GUI about the result. You don't say what problems there was with this approach. There are framworks to make this easier, like [OTL](http://otl.17slon.com/) and [AsyncCalls](http://andy.jgknet.de/blog/bugfix-units/asynccalls-29-asynchronous-function-calls/).

Comment: with cross-platform support in XE2+, are there still the same options?

Comment: No - API's are different :(  That siad, it doesn't mean that similar approaches to overall design cannot be used.  Later Delphi versions have better built-in thread, and inter-thread comms, support, perhaps to the point where they are useable :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Is the 'Orignal Delphi' way, forces the background thread to wait until the synchronized method has been executed and exposes the system to more deadlock-potential than I am happy with.  TThread.Synchronize has been re-written at least twice.  I used it once, on D3, and had problems.  I looked at how it worked.  I never used it again.

2) I the design I use most often.  I use app-lifetime threads, (or thread pools), create inter-thread comms objects and queue them to background threads using a producer-consumer queue based on a TObjectQueue descendant.  The background thread/s operate on the data/methods of the object, store results in the object and, when complete, PostMessage() the object, (cast to lParam) back to the main thread for GUI display of results in a message-handler, (cast the lParam back again).  The background threads in the main GUI thread then never have to operate on the same object and never have to directly access any fields of each other.

I use a hidden window of the GUI thread, (created with RegisterWindowClass and CreateWindow), for the background threads to PostMessage to, comms object in LParam and 'target' TwinControl, (usually a TForm class), as WParam.  The trivial wndproc for the hidden window just uses TwinControl.Perform() to pass on the LParam to a message-handler of the form.  This is safer than PostMessaging the object directly to a TForm.handle - the handle can, unfortunately, change if the window is recreated.  The hidden window never calls RecreateWindow() and so its handle never changes.

Producer-consumer queues 'out from GUI', inter-thread comms classes/objects and PostMessage() 'in to GUI' WILL work well - I've been doing it for decades.

Re-using the comms objects is fairly easy too - just create a load in a loop at startup, (preferably in an initialization section so that the comms objects outlive all forms), and push them onto a P-C queue - that's your pool.  It's easier if the comms class has a private field for the pool instance - the 'releaseBackToPool' method then needs no parameters and, if there is more than one pool, ensures that the objects are always released back to their own pool.

3) Can't really improve on David Hefferman's comment.  Just don't do it.

Comment: "This is safer than PostMessaging the object directly to a TForm.handle - the handle can, unfortunately, change if the window is recreated."  What might trigger the recreation of a window?  Is it only if the programmer explicitly destroys and recreates a window, or can it happen in other ways too?  If it can happen in other ways, can it happen to an app's main form?

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Can you elaborate on how exception handling fits in with your approach?

Comment: @RobertFrank, a form recreates the handle when borderstyle,bordericon etc is changed, see also [PostMessage returns “invalid window handle” in thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3474466/576719). Martin James has posted an example how to do the hidden window, I will look it up. Used it for many applications.

Comment: Found it, here is the link: [PostToMainThread](http://borland.newsgroups.archived.at/public.delphi.language.delphi.win32/200603/060330160.html).

Comment: @LURD Thanks for taking the time to answer and to dig up the links.

Answer (score 5):

You can implement the pattern questioned by using OTL as demonstrated by the OTL author [here](http://www.thedelphigeek.com/2012/07/asyncawait-in-delphi.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could communicate data between threads as messages.

Thread1:

1. allocate memory for a data structure
2. fill it in
3. send a message to Thread2 with the pointer to this structure (you could either use Windows messages or implement a queue, insuring its enque and dequeue methods don't have race conditions)
4. possibly receive a response message from Thread2...

Thread2:

1. receive the message with the pointer to the data structure from Thread1
2. consume the data
3. deallocate the data structure's memory
4. possibly send a message back to Thread1 in a similar fashion (perhaps reusing the data structure, but then you don't deallocate it)

You may end up with more than 1 non-GUI thread if you want your GUI not only live, but also responding to some input, while the input that takes long time to be processed is being processed.