# Delphi XE2, vcl styles recreating window handle

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, vcl-styles

After applying a new style at runtime the MainForm of my application creates a new window handle – is there any way to stop this or reassign the Handle as I a getting a tonne of the following error:

'System Error. Code: 1400. Invalid window handle'

Is there any way to manipulate the process that forces the new handle to be assigned?

I solved this doing the following:

My main form created an unseen 'helper' form that is never displayed, but that does have visual components - it was throwing the handle error when it was trying to redraw these visual components, so I replaced the relevant components with objects instead (note I did not write this code originally).

Comment: Do not store copies of the window handle (especially in threads), see [`PostMessage returns “invalid window handle” in thread`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3474227/576719).

Comment: Yes there are ways to avoid that. If you would tell us why it happens then we could help. So, why do you have a stale window handle?

Comment: FWIW, changing style in Delphi 10.4 also changes the handle of the main form. I am using EnumWindows afresh if I need to determine form handles, no longer storing them.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to avoid re-creating the window handles. Instead, override your window's `CreateWnd` and `DestroyWnd` methods so that you're notified when a window is re-created.

Also, avoid keeping persistent references to handles of windows that might get destroyed. Instead, read the `Handle` property each time you need it. Then you won't have to watch for notifications.

Beware of reading `Handle` from a different thread, though, since it may cause the window to become associated with the wrong thread. Wrap any code that needs to interact with a VCL window into a method that you call via `Synchronize` or `Queue`.