# Why TForm.Handle is a getter instead of a field?

Tags: delphi, handle, vcl, tform

*I was debugging a complicated bug recently. It was caused by accessing a non-existing `Form.Handle` (garbaged pointer). The bug revealed itself in rather unexpected way for me - accessing Forms `Handle` caused resizes and repaints.*

I would expect accessing `Form.Handle` by a garbage pointer would just return some garbage THandle. Expecting that the `Handle` is created once on form creation and stays the same till the Form is destroyed.

### The question

Why is it so, that `TForm.Handle` is not a field that gets initialized on form creation and is accessed via

```
property Handle: Integer read FHandle;
```

, but is a getter

```
property Handle: Integer read GetHandle;
```

that creates the Handle and even the Window (`CreateWnd`) on first access?

Comment: See [Delphi XE2, vcl styles recreating window handle](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15894918/576719) and [PostMessage returns “invalid window handle” in thread](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3474466/576719). In short, windows needs to recreate the handle in certain situations.

Comment: Read about VCL window recreation

Comment: Because changing certain properties of the window require it to be destroyed and recreated (see `RecreateWnd` and count the number of times it is called in the Forms unit). The *complicated bug* was caused by your not understanding the Form.Handle properly, not a problem with how TForm uses it's handle. :-)

Comment: The question seems to relate/mix the structure of the property with window [re]creation. That's why you get comments on one of the topics and an answer on the other.

Comment: Not a bug, but severe misconception. Your assumption is simply invalid. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21011780 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/582903

Comment: @FreeConsulting Did you read the question? The text in *italic* is not the problem, it's just an intro.

Comment: @Kromster, yes I did. This is by design, because some of window/control styles **are not settable** by `SetWindowLong` on live `HWND`, but have an effect at `CreateWindow` call only. So, VCL owns the handle thru `HandleAllocated`, `HandleNeeded`, `CreateHandle` etc

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The form *object* can exist even when the underlying OS *window* doesn't. During those times, the `Handle` field would be 0, which isn't helpful to code that needs a valid window handle. To ensure you get a valid handle each time you need one, you'd need to call `HandleNeeded` prior to referring to the `Handle` field. As a property with a getter, the property can call `HandleNeeded` for you automatically, making it easier to use the `Handle` property.

Comment: "making it easier" except times when accessing Handle from different thread, which looks like a really bad idea now on.

Comment: Yep. Call `HandleAllocated` first, in those cases, to guess whether subsequent access of `Handle` might be valid. You can't *know*, because the main thread might destroy the window between time of check and time of use. Ultimately, about doing UI stuff in other threads. If another thread *needs* to know a window handle, make the main thread provide the handle to the other thread (rather than the other thread fetching the handle itself), and also make the main thread take on the responsibility of ensuring the provided handle remains valid for as long as the other thread needs it.

Comment: @Kromster, if you want access to the form handle from a thread in order to send/post messages, it would probably be a better idea to allocate a handle with `AllocateHwnd()` in the main thread, and let the thread post messages to this handle. From there messages could be forwarded to the VCL.

Comment: I'd say it more strongly than @LURD. The rule is that you **never** use a VCL window handle outside of the main thread because they are subject to recreation. So you use a window handle that is not, for instance one from `AllocateHWnd`.