# When does a VCL application get its Application->MainForm->Handle?

Tags: c++, c++builder, vcl

My application populates some panels by means of incoming messages, using the `SendStructMessage()` function in `Message.hpp`.

`SendStructMessage()` need a valid windows handle to send to.

I have encapsulated the `SendStrucMessage()` in a function, like this:

```
bool sendAppMessage(ApplicationMessageEnum msgID, void* s)
{
    if(!Application || !Application->MainForm || !Application->MainForm->Handle)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Failed to get a valid handle when trying to send application message";
        return false;
    }
    HWND h = Application->MainForm->Handle;

    AppMessageStruct data;
    data.mMessageEnum = msgID;
    data.mData = s;

    LRESULT res =  SendStructMessage(h, UWM_MESSAGE, 0, &data);
    if(res)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Sending message: "<<msgID<<" was unsuccesful";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Trying to call this from either the MainForm's `OnShow` or `OnCreate` event doesn't work, as in either case the `Application->MainForm->Handle` is still NULL.

My question is, in a VCL application's startup phase, where can one be sure that the `Application->MainForm->Handle` is actually created?

Currently I kick off a Timer checking for a valid handle:

```
void __fastcall TMain::WaitForHandleTimerTimer(TObject *Sender)
{
    if(Application->MainForm->Handle)
    {
        WaitForHandleTimer->Enabled = false;

        //Send a message to main ui to update sequence shortcuts
        if(sendAppMessage(abSequencerUpdate) != true)
        {
            Log(lDebug)<<"Sending sequencer update to UI was unsuccesful";
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37614161/62576) and it's comments (as well as the answer) may help. While it's tagged Delphi, the VCL is entirely written in that language and the same information applies. The comments to the question contain some other links that are relevant here and should be extremely useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `TWinControl::Handle` property getter creates a new `HWND` at the time the property is read, if an `HWND` hasn't already been created yet.  If an error occurs while creating the `HWND`, an exception will be thrown.

So, your `!Handle` condition will *always* be false, because the `Handle` property can *never* return NULL (the `WindowHandle` property can, though).

```
bool sendAppMessage(ApplicationMessageEnum msgID, void* s)
{
    if (!((Application) && (Application->MainForm)))
    {
        Log(lError) << "Failed to get a valid handle when trying to send application message";
        return false;
    }

    AppMessageStruct data;
    data.mMessageEnum = msgID;
    data.mData = s;

    LRESULT res = SendStructMessage(Application->MainForm->Handle, UWM_MESSAGE, 0, &data);
    if (res)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Sending message: " << msgID << " was unsuccesful";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

If you want to check if the `Handle` has been created without actually creating it, use the Form's `HandleAllocated()` method:

```
bool sendAppMessage(ApplicationMessageEnum msgID, void* s)
{
    if (!((Application) && (Application->MainForm) && (Application->MainForm->HandleAllocated())))
    {
        Log(lError) << "Failed to get a valid handle when trying to send application message";
        return false;
    }

    AppMessageStruct data;
    data.mMessageEnum = msgID;
    data.mData = s;

    LRESULT res = SendStructMessage(Application->MainForm->Handle, UWM_MESSAGE, 0, &data);
    if (res)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Sending message: " << msgID << " was unsuccesful";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Otherwise, don't use `SendMessage()`/`SendStructMessage()` at all.  You can call the Form's `Perform()` method instead, which will deliver the message directly to the Form's assigned `WindowProc` without requiring any `HWND` at all:

```
bool sendAppMessage(ApplicationMessageEnum msgID, void* s)
{
    if (!((Application) && (Application->MainForm))
    {
        Log(lError) << "Failed to get a valid handle when trying to send application message";
        return false;
    }

    AppMessageStruct data;
    data.mMessageEnum = msgID;
    data.mData = s;

    LRESULT res = Application->MainForm->Perform(UWM_MESSAGE, 0, (LPARAM)&data);
    if (res)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Sending message: " << msgID << " was unsuccesful";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Alternatively, consider removing the `MainForm` dependency from `sendAppMessage()`.  You can send to `Application->Handle` instead, and then have the `MainForm` register a callback method using `Application->HookMainWindow()`.

```
bool sendAppMessage(ApplicationMessageEnum msgID, void* s)
{
    if (!((Application) && (Application->Handle))
    {
        Log(lError) << "Failed to get a valid handle when trying to send application message";
        return false;
    }

    AppMessageStruct data;
    data.mMessageEnum = msgID;
    data.mData = s;

    LRESULT res = SendStructMessage(Application->Handle, UWM_MESSAGE, 0, &data);
    if (res)
    {
        Log(lError) << "Sending message: " << msgID << " was unsuccesful";
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

__fastcall TMainForm::TMainForm(TComponent *Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
    Application->HookMainWindow(&AppMessage);
}

__fastcall TMainForm::~TMainForm()
{
    Application->UnhookMainWindow(&AppMessage);
}

bool __fastcall TMainForm::AppMessage(TMessage &Message)
{
    if (Message.Msg == UWM_MESSAGE)
    {
        WindowProc(Message);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Proposed alternative messaging mechanisms seem really valuable! Especially the Perform method.